# Entity Framework Core not adding records

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add a set of records with Entity Framework Core. For some reason I cannot get the records to actually save to the database.

Below is the code running. There are not exceptions thrown.

```
using (var context = new UserEntity.UsersContext())
{
    foreach(var u in users)
    {
        var tempUser = await context.User.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == u.Username);

        if (tempUser == null)
        {
            context.Add(u);
        }

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }                
}
```

When I watch the debugger, the program stops running when it gets to the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` call. If I remove that, the program will run fine, but `SaveChangesAsync` still does not actually insert the records to the database.

Could someone advise? Thanks

Edit 1:

```
await DataWork(smallList);
```

Edit 2 RESOLUTION!:

This is completely my fault from over looking the fact that this is a console app, as it is going to be used once and never seen again. The main method on a console app cannot be truly asynchronous.

My solution below:

```
MyAsyncMethod().Wait();
```

That's it. It works after this. Thank you all for spending the time to try to help me, it pushed me in the right direction

Comment: How are you calling the method where this code exists? Sounds like an async deadlock.

Comment: @DavidG just updated the question

Comment: @Marie this is a set of data that is being pieced together is another place. I am checking to make sure I do not enter a duplicate record into the DB

Comment: Sorry, i see now!

Comment: @MikeViscontini And up the chain from that call? Do you use `task.Result` somewhere by any chance?

Comment: This seems to be fine, we need the rest of the code to know what is happening exactly. Try to paste multiple layers of calles. Maybe we can identify the problem

Comment: If you set your breakpoint to the if condition, will the application hit the breakpoint or is your application stuck at the FirstOrDefaultAsync? And are you sure that there are new users that should get added?

Comment: @bachph When I watch the code run, and i remove the async operator on the first or default call, it properly returns null, adds to context, then saves all changed. However, the changes are not committed. When the async operator is present, the console app closes itself without throwing an exception. I have the 'DataWork' function enclosed in a try-catch

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin All the code is doing that isnt here, is reading an Excel sheet and creating Entity objects

Comment: How are you verifying the commit does not occur? What database platform are you using? Perhaps you are using localdb and overwritting the DB with every execution of your code (F5 from VS). There is simply not enough information to tell you where you are going wrong, the best we can do is guess.

Comment: @Igor I run a count on records in sql. The number should increment by 25. This is a dummy set of data i am testing with and i know there are 25 unique records

Comment: Just to help simplify things a bit you can probably do an [ExistsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.relationaldatabasecreator.existsasync?view=efcore-2.1) call rather than a FirstOrDefault + null check

Comment: Use try-catch for undrestand problem.SavechangesAsync is better to be out of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently mixing **async** and non **async** calls. Currently the **Add** methods should be **AddAsync**

If you want async operation your code should be :

```
using (var context = new UserEntity.UsersContext())
        {
            foreach(var u in users)
            {
                var tempUser = await context.User.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == u.Username);
                if (tempUser == null)
                {
                    await context.AddAsync(u);
                }

                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }                
        }
```

Comment: I have tried using addasync, but i get the same results as above

Comment: This code is on a method, is the method async too ? Like async Task AddUsers()? If you fail only one await or async, the insertion will fail, so you should review all your process and look if you are missing one somewhere

Comment: Yes the calling method is async as well

Comment: Ok I am actually thinking that this is happening because I am doing this in a console app.. I think your response has nudged me in the right direction

Comment: yep, if you are calling it directly is the main of the program your can try to wrap it in a Task with `Task.Run(async () => await DataWork(smallList);).Wait()` to keep to asynchronous behaviours :)

Comment: @Orcus - this fixed for me too in a ASP.Net Core app.   I don't undertand why I need it but it fixed it for me.  Does Wait() make it blocking again?

Comment: @Sam It's because async & non async does not share the same context. You need to remember that async & await run threads (aka is not multithreading)